# SQL TempDB swells to unmanageable size

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

We're using SQL server 2014 SP4. Out of several stored procedures, there's a particular one that  creates about 30 very large temp tables (wasn't created by myself). The process is run via daily SQL agent/schedule.

After this process runs, we've noticed that the TempDB swells to 50GB+, well after the procedure finishes running. The only workaround has been to manually shrink using the `DBCC SHRINKFILE`command, and in some cases, reboot the server.

Another observation is that the temp tables still linger around in the TempDB minutes, hours, days the procedure runs.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what?  Is there an actual problem?  If you need a 50GB TempDb, you need it.  If you shrink it, it will just have to grow again.

Comment: It causes the HDD to reach full capacity, bringing the whole server to a hault. My question is - Why does TempDB stay bloated well after the procedure is done running? Shouldn't all temp tables clear when finished executing?

Comment: Databases don't shrink automatically.  It should grow to a high-water mark, and then when temp tables are no longer in use, it will have free space.  If TempDb is filling up the disk then set a Maxsize for its files that leaves enough room for the system to operate.  If this causes your job to fail, then you need to fix the job or get more space.

Comment: Also, the "leftover" temp tables you see is probably just a caching/optimization that the engine does so that 1 page is allocated for the temp table the next time the proc executes. I. e., they do not eat anu storage to call home about.

Answer (score 2):

Side note in addition to what was already said: One reason databases don't automatically shrink is because there's a performance benefit to not have to re-grow the file on the disk. SQL Server makes use of this improved performance by internally managing the space of the file and overwriting it with new data as it needs, so it doesn't have to wait for a growth operation on the disk.

So while the file on the disk, from the OS's perspective is full, internally to your SQL Server instance it's empty and available for re-use. So things are operating as expected in your case.